# Secure binary search in C

Tags: c, algorithm

Theoretically most of the binary search algorithm implementations are broken, in the sense that the program can hit a segmentation fault for large arrays. For example, this is the case for the below implementation.

```
int binarysearch(int x, int *v, int n) {
    int l, h, m;
    l = 0;
    h = n - 1;

    while (l <= h) {
        m = (l + h) / 2;

        if (x < v[m]) h = m - 1;
        else if (x > v[m]) l = m + 1;
        else return m;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main (void) 
{
    int n = (INT_MAX/4) * 3;
    int *v = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    (void) binarysearch(1, v, n);
    cfree(v);
}
```

My question is, how would a secure version of the implementation of binary search algorithm would look like?

Comment: if (n > MAX_SUPPORTED_SIZE) return -1;

Comment: @jpa: depends on where you planned to put that statement...

Comment: Just a thought regarding the code here (and code you write in the future): While code like this does compile and run, it's not easy for others to read. Since you're posting this on a site asking others for help with it, it would be beneficial for everybody involved if you spent a little more time on naming the variables something meaningful (i.e. l -> low, h -> high, ...). This way people looking at it aren't forced to figure that out.

Comment: Actually, this is one of those few occasions, when you can get away with short variable names...

Comment: How would this result in a segmentation fault?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Index `m` becomes negative on `int` overflow.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Midpoint calculation can result in integer overflow.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use correct types -- `size_t` instead of `int` for indexes and sizes...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: That doesn't solve the problem.  Unsigned types like `size_t` can still overflow, resulting in `l+h` becoming extremely small (in particular, smaller than `l`) and `(l+h)/2` smaller still.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: `size_t` is guarenteed to be large enough to hold the size of any allocatable object, so as long as the `calloc` call did not fail, the addition won't overflow...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Right, but it's *not* guaranteed to be large enough to hold *twice* the size of any allocatable object, and `l+h` can reach that (or perhaps that minus one) if the object to be found occurs at or near the end of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problematic portion of the code is its midpoint calculation:

```
m = (l + h) / 2;
```

will produce a wrong result on `int` overflow. You can avoid this either by switching to `long long` calculation, or by employing a safe formula:

```
m = (h - l)/2 + l;
```

See [*Binary Search - Arithmetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Arithmetic) for details.

Comment: Or simply `m = l/2 + h/2`

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: That doesn't work if `l` and `h` are both odd.

Comment: Simpler than my one and also faster by one operation, very nice :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Could you elaborate?  (What is "it" here, and what is "the algorithm"?)

Comment: Even in the standard binary search function in the libraries of languages like C and Java, this bug had prevailed for years!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Huh? SomeWittyUsername's formula will cause binary search to loop forever if `l` is odd and `h=l+2`.

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful to point out where the error occurs -- namely, the computation of `m = (l + h) / 2;` can fail if `l + h` overflows the range of positive integers.  In that case, the answer will become negative, and the signed integer division will propagate the sign bit, producing a smaller negative number, which is interpreted as a very large unsigned positive number when it's used as an array index.

I don't remember where I saw it, but there's a cute trick that lets you safely compute the average of 2 numbers even if their sum exceeds machine precision.  Essentially, given any two numbers `a` and `b`, notice that

```
a = (a & b) | (a & ~b)   # Each bit in a is either shared with b, or not
  = (a & b) + (a & ~b)   # Since these two terms share no bits
b = (a & b) | (b & ~a)
  = (a & b) + (b & ~a)   # Likewise
```

So

```
(a + b) / 2 = [  (a & b) + (a & ~b) + (a & b) + (b & ~a) ] / 2
            = [2*(a & b) + (a & ~b) + (b & ~a)] / 2
            = [2*(a & b)] / 2 + [(a & ~b) + (b & ~a)] / 2
            = (a & b) + [(a & ~b) + (b & ~a)] / 2
```

Finally, notice that the expression `(a & ~b) + (b & ~a)` on the RHS is simply every bit that is in a, or in b, but not in both -- IOW, it is `a ^ b`.  Therefore we have

```
(a + b) / 2 = (a & b) + (a ^ b) / 2
```

with no possibility of overflow.